# Default UILevel WIX

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

Is there a way to set the default UILevel for my WIX msi? Like if I were to pass /passive to msiexec?

I tried setting a property for UILevel to 2...but that didn't work of course.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`LIMITUI` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369759.aspx) to restrict your UI to basic/passive.